# SQL: Efficiently finding minimum data points within separate subranges for each column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query (targeting SQL Server, sadly) which looks something like this:

```
SELECT
    DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(ts), MONTH(ts), DAY(ts), 0, 0, 0, 0) AS day,
    AVG(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, ts) = 0 THEN val ELSE NULL END) AS hr0,
    AVG(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, ts) = 1 THEN val ELSE NULL END) AS hr1,
    -- ...etc for other hours...
FROM 
    sample_data
GROUP BY 
    DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(ts), MONTH(ts), DAY(ts), 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

This works perfectly well, calculating (for each day) an average value for each hour.

My requirements are changing, however: I'm now asked for only the *first* sample for each hour. Thus, `hr0` should reflect only a single `value` for the smallest `ts` satisfying `DATEPART(HOUR, ts) = 0` (and, of course, still being within the same day), or a NULL if none exist.

The obvious approach that comes to mind is using a subquery for each hour, but this strikes me as a significant decrease in runtime efficiency (and my implementation attempts are not only slow but also *ugly*). Is there a better alternative I'm not considering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To truncate time component from `datetime` you can simply cast to `date`.

Look up `top-n-per-group` or `greatest-n-per-group`. For SQL Server see [Retrieving n rows per group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group).

Here is one possible variant using `ROW_NUMBER()`.

The `WHERE rn=1` filter results in at most one row per hour. Each row would contain first `val` for this hour.

The `GROUP BY dt` together with 24 `MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, ts) = ...` pivots the result set to make one row per day with 24 columns for each hour. Here instead of `MIN` you can put any other aggregating function (`MAX`, `SUM`, `AVG`). The result would not change, because after the first filter there can be at most one row per hour.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ts
        ,CAST(ts as date) AS dt
        ,val
        ,ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(ts as date), DATEPART(HOUR, ts) ORDER BY ts) AS rn
    FROM sample_data
)
SELECT
    dt
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, ts) = 0 THEN val ELSE NULL END) AS hr0
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, ts) = 1 THEN val ELSE NULL END) AS hr1
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, ts) = 2 THEN val ELSE NULL END) AS hr2
    -- ...etc for other hours...
FROM CTE
WHERE rn=1
GROUP BY dt
ORDER BY dt;
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3eec3/1/0) with your sample data.